# Windows 8.1 upgrade to windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-10-upgrade

Helping a friend build a computer and his budget is tight for what we want. I was wondering, considering that windows 10 came as a free upgrade to windows 8.1 users, and as windows 8.1 is like 50 bucks cheaper than windows 10. Wouldn't it be possible to buy a copy of windows 8.1 and just "upgrade" to windows 10?

Comment: The upgrade cannot be transferred to other PCs. That means he’ll be stuck with Windows 8.1 should he ever get a new PC.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12435/windows-10-upgrade-faq):

> The free upgrade offer to Windows 10 will end on July 29, 2016.

Simply make sure that the computer is compatible by verifying its hardware requirements on [the Windows 10 specifications page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications?OCID=win10_null_vanity_win10specs).

If everything looks good, your plan should definitely work.

Comment: muhahah i hope so